# Time complexity of a python program with nested loops

Tags: python

This is regarding finding the time complexity of a python program which involves nested loops.

```
def Function(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n / 2, n):
        j = 1
        while j + n / 2 <= n:
            k = 1
            while k <= n:
                count = count + 1
                k = k * 2
            j = j + 1

    print (count)

Function(20)
```

I'm trying to find out the complexity but little confused with the arguments in range function and so much of nested loops.
I got stuck while finding the time complexity of the second loops and the inner most.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, let us begin with the inner while loop, we can clearly see that this condition holds true only when `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * ... k times <= n`
i.e `2^k <= n`
for calculating the time complexity we can say

```
2^k = n
```

taking `log base 2` both side we get `k = log2 (n)`
so we can say that the inner loop executes `log2 (n)` times.

Coming to the middle loop which has again a constrain `j+n/2 <= n`, and `j` is being incremented by 1 each time this loop is running. So if you think a little bit you can say that it will execute `n/2` times.

And coming to the outer loop you can directly see the `range(n/2, n)` which I think gives you idea about the execution of that loop. i.e `n/2` times again.
So overall time complexity is `O((n/2) * (n/2) * log2 (n))` which you can say is `O(n^2 log2 (n))`

below I have edited your program with the comments in it.

```
def Function(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n / 2, n):  # Outer loop execute n/2 times
        j = 1
        while j + n / 2 <= n:  # Middle loop executes n/2 times
            k = 1
            while k <= n:  # Inner loop execute logn times
                count = count + 1
                k = k * 2
            j = j + 1

    print (count)

Function(20)
```

you can watch some videos on youtube which will teach you to find the time complexity of programs.